# Android emulator on wayland : Emulator terminated with exit code 134

Tags: android, android-emulator, wayland

I've got the following error when trying to run android emulator from android studio.
I'm on Manjaro (Arch linux) under a wayland graphic manager.

```
WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 134
```

I've tried with many device including Nexus 4 without playstore so that I can tweak RAM to 2GiB and the graphic performance to "software". But nothing do the trick I'm always facing this issue.

Answer (score 13):

After trying to run the emulator from command line (`~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Nexus_4_API_25`),  I got this more explicit error:

```
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

It's related to the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` environment variable which must be setted to `xcb` to force the app to run undex XWayland instead of native wayland.

`QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Nexus_4_API_25`

or with android-studio: (including _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 for avoid blank window)

`QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 android-studio`

Hope this can help someone else struggling against this issue.